# UITableView another cell image also changes when selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having an UITableView in which there are seven sections some sections have expandable rows in it. When a expandable section is clicked it's 0th row should change image and it is doing but last section which is not expandable it's row also get image changed but when i shuffle table view everything gets ok. Posting the images below to make clear what is happening.

[image: first screen]

[image: When expandable section clicked some other rows image also change]

[image: At same screen when another expandable section clicked it affects the previous expanded section also.]

Below posting my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

if(tableView == self.mWeekTable)
{
    cell = [self.mWeekTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sub_cell.png"]];
    //myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:219.0/255.0 green:218.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.backgroundView = myBackgroundView;
    [cell addSubview:myBackgroundView];

    UILabel *lblDateTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 30)];
    lblDateTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22];
    lblDateTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:169.0/255.0 green:168.0/255.0 blue:176.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    lblDateTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *lblEName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 170, 25)];
    lblEName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    lblEName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:247.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    lblEName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imgTimer = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 26, 20, 22)];

    UILabel *lblTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 150, 25)];
    lblTime.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    lblTime.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imgCateg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(175, 26, 20, 22)];

    UILabel *lblCateg = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 28, 90, 20)];
    //self.lblCateg.text = @"Category";
    lblCateg.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
    lblCateg.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lblCateg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    NSString *weekDate = [[NSString alloc]init];

    UILabel *lblEventsCount = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 16, 100, 20)];
    lblEventsCount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblEventsCount.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:247.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    lblEventsCount.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];

    int evntCnt;

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
         evntCnt = [self.mArrDayOneEvents count];
        if(!isWeekListOne)
        {

            NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd"];
            weekDate = [df stringFromDate:[self.mArrDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
            lblDateTitle.text = weekDate;

            if(evntCnt == 0)
            {
                myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_blank.png"]];
            }
            else{
                myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg+.png"]];
                lblEventsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Events", evntCnt];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
               [cell addSubview:lblEventsCount];
                NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd"];
                weekDate = [df stringFromDate:[self.mArrDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
                lblDateTitle.text = weekDate;

                if(evntCnt == 0)
                {
                    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_blank.png"]];
                }
                else{
                    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg-.png"]];
                    lblEventsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Events", evntCnt];
                }
            }
            else{
                int ind = indexPath.row;
                ind--;
               // cell.textLabel.text = [self.mArrDayOneEvents objectAtIndex:ind];
                lblEName.text = [self.mArrDayOneEvents objectAtIndex:ind];
                imgTimer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timer1.png"];
            }
        }
        }
    [cell addSubview:lblDateTitle];
    [cell addSubview:lblEName];
    [cell addSubview:lblCateg];
    [cell addSubview:lblTime];
    [cell addSubview:imgCateg];
    [cell addSubview:imgTimer];
    [cell addSubview:lblEventsCount];
```

}

Not posting the full code because other sections also have same code as above and below.

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         if(tableView == self.mWeekTable)
  {
      int evntCnt;
      if(indexPath.section == 0)
      {
           evntCnt = [self.mArrDayOneEvents count];
          if(indexPath.row == 0)
          {
              isWeekListOne  = !isWeekListOne;

              if(isWeekListOne)
              {
                  if(evntCnt == 0)
                  {
                      myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_blank.png"]];
                  }
                  else{
                      myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg-.png"]];
                  }

              }
              else{
                  if(evntCnt == 0)
                  {
                      myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_blank.png"]];
                  }
                  else{
                      myBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bg+.png"]];
                  }
              }
              selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.row;
              [self.mWeekTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
          }
      }
}
```

int evntCnt is used to check those sections which have events. If anything not clear please ask. Looking for help in the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you always creating a new cell, even if you manage to dequeue one?

Comment: And I'm guessing all your cell identifiers are the same string and sometimes you use the dequeued cell and sometimes you create a new cell?

Comment: @Wain found a couple of bugs and removed but issue not solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is related to cell reuse. Generally, there are 2 things to look at:

1. Ensure that every different configuration uses a different cell identifier (with a different value)
2. When you reuse a cell, reset everything

At the moment, you're adding a lot of subviews to your cells. These aren't removed when the cell is reused. So, images stay there and show up on rows where they shouldn't be. Your best option is to use custom cell subclasses so your code doesn't have all that subview creation and add a simple way to set the mode of the cell which shows and hides the appropriate subviews. Then always set the mode when you create/reuse a cell.